# Using geo_polygon and geo_bounding_box filter together in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and trying to use geo_bounding_box and geo_polygon filters together in a search. They work if I use them separately one by one. But if I try using them, it gives me error. Here is my code.

```
$json = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must_not' => [
                    ['terms' => ['_id' => []]],
                    ['terms' => ['rarity' => []]]
                ],
                'must' => [
                    'range' => [
                        'disappearTime' => [
                            'gte' => 'now',
                            'lte' => 'now+1d'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'geo_bounding_box' => [
                        'location' => [
                            'top_left' => [
                                'lat' => 52.280577919216356,
                                'lon' => -113.78533601760866
                            ],
                            'bottom_right' => [
                                'lat' => 52.26306210545918,
                                'lon' => -113.81855249404909
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'geo_polygon' => [
                        'location' => [
                            "points" => [
                                [-113.78721646175813, 52.29637194474555],
                                [-113.76335508934484, 52.281770664368565],
                                [-113.76335508934484, 52.26112133563143],
                                [-113.78721646175813, 52.24652005525444],
                                [-113.82096153824187, 52.24652005525444],
                                [-113.84482291065517, 52.26112133563143],
                                [-113.84482291065517, 52.281770664368565],
                                [-113.82096153824187, 52.29637194474555],
                                [-113.78721646175813, 52.29637194474555],
                                [-113.69997059121626, 52.298658944745554],
                                [-113.67610798767082, 52.28405766436857],
                                [-113.67610798767082, 52.26340833563143],
                                [-113.69997059121626, 52.248807055254446],
                                [-113.73371740878373, 52.248807055254446],
                                [-113.75758001232917, 52.26340833563143],
                                [-113.75758001232917, 52.28405766436857],
                                [-113.73371740878373, 52.298658944745554],
                                [-113.69997059121626, 52.298658944745554]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to put each geo filter inside its own PHP Array, like you did with the `terms` queries in the `bool/must` clause

```
$json = [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must_not' => [
                ['terms' => ['_id' => []]],
                ['terms' => ['rarity' => []]]
            ],
            'must' => [
                'range' => [
                    'disappearTime' => [
                        'gte' => 'now',
                        'lte' => 'now+1d'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'filter' => [
              [
                'geo_bounding_box' => [
                    'location' => [
                        'top_left' => [
                            'lat' => 52.280577919216356,
                            'lon' => -113.78533601760866
                        ],
                        'bottom_right' => [
                            'lat' => 52.26306210545918,
                            'lon' => -113.81855249404909
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
              ],
              [
                'geo_polygon' => [
                    'location' => [
                        "points" => [
                            [-113.78721646175813, 52.29637194474555],
                            [-113.76335508934484, 52.281770664368565],
                            [-113.76335508934484, 52.26112133563143],
                            [-113.78721646175813, 52.24652005525444],
                            [-113.82096153824187, 52.24652005525444],
                            [-113.84482291065517, 52.26112133563143],
                            [-113.84482291065517, 52.281770664368565],
                            [-113.82096153824187, 52.29637194474555],
                            [-113.78721646175813, 52.29637194474555],
                            [-113.69997059121626, 52.298658944745554],
                            [-113.67610798767082, 52.28405766436857],
                            [-113.67610798767082, 52.26340833563143],
                            [-113.69997059121626, 52.248807055254446],
                            [-113.73371740878373, 52.248807055254446],
                            [-113.75758001232917, 52.26340833563143],
                            [-113.75758001232917, 52.28405766436857],
                            [-113.73371740878373, 52.298658944745554],
                            [-113.69997059121626, 52.298658944745554]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Can you check this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195348/calculate-average-of-an-arrays-indexes-in-elasticsearch